# how to get value of column from sys_refcursor returned by a function being called

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am calling a function `pck_my_pack`.`f_my_func` in my anonymous block , `f_my_func` returns a `sys_refcursor`.

I want the value of `req_column` from `sys_refcursor` to used as

```
IF req_column>0 THEN 
 do this and that
END IF;
```

Problem is `sys_refcursor` which is being returned by `my_func` does not select values from a specific table. it selects values from multiple tables and few locals variables which were calculated in `my_func`.

Please help me out to get the value from this `sys_refcursor`. 
Here is what I am trying:

```
DECLARE 
TYPE cu_income_detail is ref cursor;
income_det cu_income_detail;
BEGIN 

    income_det := pck_my_pack.f_my_func(2542586);

    FOR CURRVAL IN income_det LOOP     -- I have also tried CUR_VAL
         IF CURRVAL.pcls_paid_as_income > 0 THEN 
         -- Logic yet to be implemented once get the value
         dbms_output.put('PCLS paid');  
         dbms_output.put_line(CUR_VAL.pcls_paid_as_income);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Post your function code also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare 
  src_cur sys_refcursor;
  curid    NUMBER;
  v_jobtitle varchar2(35);
  v_min_salary number;
begin 
  open src_cur for 'select job_id,job_title,min_salary,max_salary from jobs';
  curid := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(src_cur);
  dbms_sql.define_column(curid,2,v_jobtitle,35);
  dbms_sql.define_column(curid,3,v_min_salary);
   WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(curid) > 0 LOOP
       DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, 2, v_jobtitle);
       DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, 3, v_min_salary);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('job_titile='||v_jobtitle||' ;min_salary='||v_min_salary);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(curid);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to know type and name of columns in your sys_refcursor. 
And perform fetch into operation on it.

```
DECLARE 
TYPE cu_income_detail is ref cursor;
income_det cu_income_detail;
BEGIN 
    income_det := pck_my_pack.f_my_func(2542586);
    loop
      fetch income_det into var_1, var_2 ... var_3;
       -- Logic here 
      exit when income_det%notfound;    
    end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Hi, 
there are more than 35 columns in that cursor.
That is why i am not fetching like that, as i just want value from one column.

Comment: I have added another answer. It is more complicated. And it 's worked from oracle 11.2